When using pandoc to convert *.tex to .*docx, my \chapter{} are vanishing
I'm using pandoc to convertsome very simple *.tex files to *.docx
It works very well except one thing : my \chapter{} ligne doesn't appears in the resulting .*docx
To be precise : if I compile my *.tex to .*pdf, I have a nice

Chapitre 1
This is the first line of an incredible novel

but the export with pandoc of my *.tex give me in the resulting *.docx :

(nothing)
This is the first line of an incredible novel

I'm doing pandoc test.tex -o text.docx
with
\documentclass[a4paper,17pt,oneside]{extbook} 
\usepackage{lmodern} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\usepackage{lettrine} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\pagestyle{plain}  
\begin{document}   
\title{My title} 
\author{Me} 
\date{2024}  
\frontmatter 
\maketitle  
\mainmatter  
\begin{onehalfspace}  
\chapter{} etc etc 

\end{onehalfspace}
\end{document}

Any idea to help me ?
Best regards.
PS : I put nothing in \chapter{} because i don't need to, as the export to pdf gives me Chapter 1 etc. and I don't need more.

Hi there
I'm doing pandoc test.tex -o text.docx
And
`\documentclass[a4paper,17pt,oneside]{extbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\date{2024}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\mainmatter
\begin{onehalfspace}
\chapter{}
etc etc`

PS : I put nothing in \chapter{} because i don't need to, as the export to pdf gives me Chapter 1 etc. and I don't need more.

Off-topic: IMHO, using \chapter{} with book or extbook is not recommend, because of the extra space, the empty title text produces. You should at least reconfigure \chapter to reduce the space after the heading.

As already told in a comment: Because of using \chapter{}, the docx file contains an empty Heading 1. The default Heading 1 paragraph style is without numbering and therefore only an empty paragraph using style Heading 1:

After activating heading numbering for paragraph style Heading 1, I also see the number of the empty chapter:

You can also configure the heading numbering to use a prefix (aka “Before”) for Heading 1 to have again “Chapter 1”:

So the conversion using pandoc does definitely not remove the chapters. How chapters are displayed with docx depends on the MS Word document style.
For more information about how to configure paragraph styles and heading numbering see the manual of your office application. For information about how to use a dedicated document styles already while converting with pandoc --reference-doc … see the pandoc user manual, because this is not a (La)TeX problem and therefore off-topic.
Related: How do I add custom formatting to docx files generated in Pandoc?
Disclaimer: All screenshots in this example show snapshots of the generated docx file using LibreOffice. The GUIs of other compatible office applications like Microsoft Office, Softmaker Office, WordPerfect, KOffice, etc. differ and therefore may show the same information differently.

Many many thanks !
